# IIS 8.5 Windows Authentication access denied

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, iis-8.5

I've been attempting to migrate our intranet websites from a IIS 6 server to Windows 2k12 R2 IIS 8.5 server. However, since all of our applications use Windows Authentication, everyone (except for the server admins) are getting 401 errors.

I've done some research ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120734/does-an-iis-7-5-web-app-with-windows-authentication-require-end-users-to-have-fi), [2](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-using-windows-authentication-with-minimal-permissions-granted-to-disk), [3](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities), [4](http://blogs.iis.net/jaroslad/archive/2010/11/01/what-does-the-authenticateduseroverrideuser-do.aspx)) and it seems that you have to setup your NTFS file permissions to allow everyone to read (and optionally write if you are accepting file uploads) to the inetpub/wwwroot folder. This seems like an awful security implementation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: hello have you had any luck with this issue. We are having the exact same problem since 2 months and still no luck.